# get maximum li height from 3 ul and add it on all

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get maximum `li` height from 3 `ul` and apply over them respectively.

For example, from first row if middle ul's li has height it will apply on to the first and third ul's `li` for the same row.

```
<div class="first_col">
    <ul>
        <li>first-ul</li>
        <li>first-ul</li>
        <li>first-ul</li>
        <li>first-ul</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sec_col">
    <ul>
        <li>sec-ul</li>
        <li>sec-ul</li>
        <li>sec-ul</li>
        <li>sec-ul</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="third_col">
    <ul>
        <li>three-ul</li>
        <li>three-ul</li>
        <li>three-ul</li>
        <li>three-ul</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var ht = [];
    $('.first_col li').each(function(index) {
        ht[index] = $(this).height();
        console.log(ht[index]);
    });

    $('.sec_col li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).css('height', ht[index]);
    });

    $('.third_col li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).css('height', ht[index]);
    });           
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping through the `li` within the first `ul`, retrieving the `li` in other `ul` at the same index and then equalising their heights. Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.first_col li').each(function(index) {
    var $li = $('ul').find('li:eq(' + index + ')');
    var height = $li.map(function() {
      return $(this).height();
    }).get();
    $li.height(Math.max.apply(this, height));
  });

});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
.first_col li:nth-child(1) {
  height: 50px;
}
.sec_col li:nth-child(3) {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first_col">
  <ul>
    <li>first-ul</li>
    <li>first-ul</li>
    <li>first-ul</li>
    <li>first-ul</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sec_col">
  <ul>
    <li>sec-ul</li>
    <li>sec-ul</li>
    <li>sec-ul</li>
    <li>sec-ul</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="third_col">
  <ul>
    <li>three-ul</li>
    <li>three-ul</li>
    <li>three-ul</li>
    <li>three-ul</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that the CSS in the above example is only to make the effect of the code more obvious, it's not required for the logic to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code for your solution,

```
function applyMaxHeightToAll(){
            var values = $('ul');
            var height = 0;
            for (var i =0; i<values.length; i++) {
              if(parseInt($(values[i]).height())>height){
                height = parseInt($(values[i]).height());
              }
            }
            for(var i =0; i<values.length; i++){
                $(values[i]).css("height",height);
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easier with jQuery.each

```
function set_max_height(){
    $('.row').each(function(){
        var max = 0;
        $(this).find('ul').each(function(){
            var h = $(this).height();
            if(h>max) max = h;
        });
        $(this).find('ul').css("height",max);
    });
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="first_col">
        <ul>
            <li>first-ul</li>
            <li>first-ul</li>
            <li>first-ul</li>
            <li>first-ul</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="sec_col">
        <ul>
            <li>sec-ul</li>
            <li>sec-ul</li>
            <li>sec-ul</li>
            <li>sec-ul</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="third_col">
        <ul>
            <li>three-ul</li>
            <li>three-ul</li>
            <li>three-ul</li>
            <li>three-ul</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```